Randomize items in HTML
I need to shuffle a list of items to create a Captcha module in Svelte, with TypeScript.
Currently I'm using the lodash package, but it appears it does not work with Amazon's MTurk, so I need to replace it with some alternative.
Is there a native way in TypeScript to perform the shuffling without the use of external libraries?
Here is my current code:
<script lang="ts">
    import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte'
    import {shuffle} from "lodash";
    const dispatchEvent = createEventDispatcher();
    
    let allImages = [];
    let imgs = [
        {
            id: 'img1',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/123900_26.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img2',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/59771_25.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img3',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/123900_43.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img4',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/173363_24.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img5',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/173363_40.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img6',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/72298_25.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img7',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/72298_55.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img8',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/86454_0.jpg",
        },
        {
            id: 'img9',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lieldvd/video_list/main/86454_9.jpg",
        },
    ];
    imgs = shuffle(imgs);

    const correctImages = ["img1", "img2", "img4", "img7", "img8"];
    let checkedImages: any = [];
    let notRobot = false;
    function checkIfRobot(event: any){
        notRobot = checkedImages.length == correctImages.length && checkedImages.every(function (element) {return correctImages.includes(element)});
    }

</script>

<main>
    <h2>I'm not a robot challenge:</h2>
    <div>
        Please complete the following challenge to assert you are human.
        In the following images choose the onse that describe a touch...
    </div>
    <div id="image-grid">
        <div id="image-container">
            {#each imgs as img, index (img.url)}
                <img src={img.url} alt={img.id} width='200' height='150'/>
                <input type="checkbox" id={img.id} value={img.id} bind:group={checkedImages}>
                {#if (index+1) % 3 == 0}
                    <br/>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button on:click={checkIfRobot}>Submit</button>
</main>


The JavaScript solutions should be easy to adapt to TypeScript, though some of them do mutate the passed-in array rather than creating a new one.
